# Using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker and issue with CancellationToken.None

Tags: c#

I am trying this code in a C# project:

```
m_Credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes, 
                                          "user", CancellationToken.None, 
                                           new FileDataStore("PTS.Cal.App"));
```

But it tells me that CancellationToken.None does not exist in the current context.

What is wrong? If I Put System.Threading.Can... then I get another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting one important thing: ".Result()" !

```
m_Credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes, _
                                          "user", CancellationToken.None, _
                                          New FileDataStore("PTS.Cal.App")).Result()
```